# Why is my particle instance object rotated?

Tags: particles

[image]

When I use the cone in the background as a particle instance object on the plane, it is rotated, as you can see. How do I get it to not do that, or rather, how do I get the cones to stand upright on the plane?

There are no rotation transformations still unapplied, I also didn't change anything in the Particle settings (other than "Hair -> Render: Object -> Object:Cone), this is just everything out-of-the-box.

Comment: Check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179606/leaf-particles-falling-through-plane/179661#179661 (hope it helps)

Comment: Oh yes, perfect